# flutter problem: dataColumn width issue and How to remove rowDivider from dataTable?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

### here i got width issue for data table and I also want every rowDivider will be remove,
and here I use animation, if you have any idea to improve animation then tell me.

here i got width issue for data table and I also want every rowDivider will be remove,
and here I use animation, if you have any idea to improve animation then tell me.

this is my full code

```
import 'package:bonanza_flutter/Constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  double _height = 60.0;
  bool _isExpanded = false;

  Future<bool> _showList() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    return true;
  }

  Future<bool> _showList1() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10));
    return true;
  }

  bool isOnPMS = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      appBar: AppBar(

      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // imageSlider(),
            pmsData(),
            // advantages(),
            // products(),
            Container(
              height: 20,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

extension WidgetExtension on _HomePageState {
  pmsData() {
    return Container(
      color: lightBlue,
      child: Column(

        children: [
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
           child: Column( crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,children: [
             Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
               children: [
                 Text(
                   "PMS",
                   style:
                   TextStyle(fontSize: tSize16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                 ),
                 Row(
                   children: [
                     Container(
                       width: 22,
                       height: 22,
                       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
                         color: skyBlue,
                       ),
                       child: Icon(
                         Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
                         color: Colors.white,
                         size: 17,
                       ),
                     ),
                     SizedBox(
                       width: 20,
                     ),
                     Container(
                       width: 22,
                       height: 22,
                       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
                         color: skyBlue,
                       ),
                       child: Icon(
                         Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
                         color: Colors.white,
                         size: 17,
                       ),
                     ),
                   ],
                 )
               ],
             ),
             SizedBox(
               height: 8,
             ),
             Text(
               "ICICI Prudential PMS",
               style: TextStyle(
                   fontSize: tSize14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: skyBlue),
             ),
             SizedBox(
               height: 12,
             ),
             Row(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
               children: [
                 Column(
                   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                   children: [
                     Text(
                       "\u{20B9} 50,00,000",
                       style: TextStyle(
                           fontSize: tSize11,
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                           color: blackColor),
                     ),
                     SizedBox(
                       height: 5,
                     ),
                     Text(
                       "ICICI Prudential PMS",
                       style: TextStyle(
                           fontSize: tSize11,
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                           color: greyColor),
                     ),
                     SizedBox(
                       height: 14,
                     ),
                     Text(
                       "\u{20B9} 2,02,993 (+4.06%)",
                       style: TextStyle(
                           fontSize: tSize11,
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                           color: green2Color),
                     ),
                     SizedBox(
                       height: 5,
                     ),
                     Text(
                       "Gains & Loss",
                       style: TextStyle(
                           fontSize: tSize11,
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                           color: greyColor),
                     ),
                   ],
                 ),
                 Column(
                   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                   children: [
                     Text(
                       "\u{20B9} 52,02,993",
                       style: TextStyle(
                           fontSize: tSize11,
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                           color: blackColor),
                     ),
                     SizedBox(
                       height: 5,
                     ),
                     Text(
                       "Current Market Value",
                       style: TextStyle(
                           fontSize: tSize11,
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                           color: greyColor),
                     ),
                     SizedBox(
                       height: 14,
                     ),
                     Text(
                       "\u{20B9} 5",
                       style: TextStyle(
                           fontSize: tSize11,
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                           color: blackColor),
                     ),
                     SizedBox(
                       height: 5,
                     ),
                     Text(
                       "Total Holdings",
                       style: TextStyle(
                           fontSize: tSize11,
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                           color: greyColor),
                     ),
                   ],
                 ),
                 SizedBox(
                   width: 0,
                 )
               ],
             ),
           ],),
         ),
          AnimatedContainer(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            height: _height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
            ),

            // padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                _isExpanded
                    ? SizedBox.shrink()
                    : FutureBuilder(
                        future: _showList1(),

                        /// will wait untill box animation completed
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                            return SizedBox();
                          }
                          return Center(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 20.0, bottom: 00, left: 70, right: 70),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                height: 25,
                                width: 100,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                      primary: skyBlue,
                                      shadowColor: Colors.transparent),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      isOnPMS = !isOnPMS;
                                      if (!_isExpanded) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          _height = 350;
                                          _isExpanded = true;
                                        });
                                      } else {
                                        setState(() {
                                          _height = 50;
                                          _isExpanded = false;
                                        });
                                      }
                                    });
                                    print(_isExpanded);
                                  },
                                  child: Text("View More"),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                _isExpanded
                    ? FutureBuilder(
                        future: _showList(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                            return SizedBox();
                          }
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 20.0, bottom: 00, left: 0, right: 0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                DataTable(
                                  columns: const <DataColumn>[
                                    DataColumn(
                                      label: Text(
                                        '#',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    DataColumn(
                                      label: Text(
                                        'STOCK',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    DataColumn(
                                      label: Text(
                                        'SECTOR',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    DataColumn(
                                      label: Text(
                                        'WEIGHT',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                  rows: const <DataRow>[
                                    DataRow(
                                      cells: <DataCell>[
                                        DataCell(Text('1')),
                                        DataCell(Text('TCS')),
                                        DataCell(Text('Global')),
                                        DataCell(Text('11%')),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    DataRow(
                                      cells: <DataCell>[
                                        DataCell(Text('2')),
                                        DataCell(Text('DMART')),
                                        DataCell(Text('Consumers')),
                                        DataCell(Text('10%')),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    DataRow(
                                      cells: <DataCell>[
                                        DataCell(Text('3')),
                                        DataCell(Text('ICICIBANK')),
                                        DataCell(Text('Financials')),
                                        DataCell(Text('12%')),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    DataRow(
                                      cells: <DataCell>[
                                        DataCell(Text('4')),
                                        DataCell(Text('RELIANCE')),
                                        DataCell(Text('Industrial')),
                                        DataCell(Text('13%')),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                  dividerThickness: 0,
                                  headingRowColor:
                                      MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                                          (states) => greyColor),
                                  headingRowHeight: 30,
                                ),
                                Center(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 20.0,
                                        bottom: 00,
                                        left: 70,
                                        right: 70),
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      height: 25,
                                      width: 100,
                                      child: ElevatedButton(
                                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                            primary: skyBlue,
                                            shadowColor: Colors.transparent),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            isOnPMS = !isOnPMS;
                                            if (!_isExpanded) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                _height = 350;
                                                _isExpanded = true;
                                              });
                                            } else {
                                              setState(() {
                                                _height = 50;
                                                _isExpanded = false;
                                              });
                                            }
                                          });
                                          print(_isExpanded);
                                        },
                                        child: const Text('View Less'),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        })
                    : SizedBox.shrink(),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want like this dataDable.
[image]

this is my ui which I created.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap DataTable with SingleChildScrollView and set scrollDirection to horizontal.
Use TableBorder to remove divider.